# C++ sqrt function precision for full squares

Tags: c++, floating-point-precision

Let, `x` is an integer and `y = x * x`.

Then is it guaranteed that `sqrt(y) == x`?

For example, can I be sure that `sqrt(25)` or `sqrt(25.0)` will return `5.0`, not `5.0000000003` or `4.999999998` ?

Comment: If 5 can't be represented exactly, how could it? The best you can hope for is that it truncates to 5.

Comment: As 5 is an integer, shouldn't it be represented exactly? I read somewhere that double can exactly store the values in the integer range.

Comment: @RafiKamal: An IEEE-754 64-bit double-precision float can accurately represent the entire range of 32-bit signed and unsigned integers without loss.  That only governs type conversions in that exact case.  It does not govern the precision of the floating point library that computes `sqrt(x)`.

Comment: related question: [Floating point inaccuracy examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples)

Comment: [IEEE double such that sqrt(x*x) ≠ x](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41656438/995714)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot be guaranteed.  For integers and their squares that fit in the dynamic range of the floating point type's mantissa (2^53 for a typical C/C++ `double`), you're likely to be OK, but not necessarily guaranteed.

You should avoid equals comparisons between floating point values and exact values, especially exact integer values.  Floating point rounding modes and other such things can really get in your way.

You either want to use a "comparison range" to accept an "approximately equal" result, or recast your algorithm in terms of integers.  There are multiple StackOverflow questions covering floating point equality comparisons.  I suggest you search for them and read up.

For a certain class of problem, I wrote up an alternate solution here:
 [Find n-th root of all numbers within an interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19881811/find-n-th-root-of-all-numbers-within-an-interval/19881930#19881930)

That solution took a different approach than relying on tricky floating point arithmetic.

Answer (score 13):

An implementation conforming to the IEEE-754 standard on allowed errors for basic operations (of which `sqrt` is an example) requires that values be correctly rounded.
This means that the error will less than 1/2 ULP (unit in the last place) or basically as close as possible to the actual answer.

To answer your question, if the actual answer is exactly representable by a `double` then you will get the exact answer.

Note: this is not guaranteed by the C++ standard but by the IEEE-754 standard, which probably isn't an issue for most people.

Ultimately, a simple test should be sufficient for your purposes:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < (int)std::sqrt(std::numeric_limits<int>::max()); i++)
    {
        assert((int)(double)i == i);//Ensure exactly representable, because why not
        assert(std::sqrt((double)i*i) == i);
    }
```

If this passes, I don't see any reason to worry.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to brute force search all the values up to 2^26 quite easily, but I believe the answer is yes. After that number, no.

The digit-by-digit textbook algorithm for square root finishes with remainder == 0, giving exact results. Then again if a floating point library claims ieee-754 compliancy, it'll give this value by any other means too.